# Set graphical signature location while creating a Signature Field with CoSign Signature API

Tags: digital-signature, cosign-api

How to set graphical signature location, left or top, while creating a Signature Field with CoSign Signature API programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default location of the graphical signature is on the left. If you want it to be on top, you need to set the `AR_PDF_SIGN_VERTICAL` flag (0x00000004) as part of the signature field’s *Flags* attribute in the `SAPI_SIG_FIELD_SETTINGS` structure.